# Big O notation with -n near zero

Tags: limits, notation, asymptotics

Given a function of the form

$$f(x)= \frac{c_1}{x} + \frac{c_2}{x^2} \,+ \,...+\, \frac{c_n}{x^n}$$

where $c_1,c_2,...,c_n \epsilon \mathbb{R}$ are constants, as $x$ approaches $0$ it is clear that $\frac{c_n}{x^n}$ dominates.

So could I say that as $x$ approaches $0,\,f(x)=\mathcal{O}\, (\frac{1}{x^n})$?

Comment: Yes, you can, since $\frac1{x^k}=o\bigl(\frac1{x^n}\bigr)$ for $k<n$.

Comment: @Bernard Ok, Thanks so much!